# How can I use literate coffeescript for my Gruntfile

Tags: coffeescript

Grunt files must either be "Gruntfile.js" or "Gruntfile.coffee". So, how can I write my Gruntfile using literate coffeescript instead of vanilla coffeescript (since, I believe, literate coffeescript files need to be named with a .litcoffee at the end instead of just .coffee)?

Comment: Nop, you can't, because Grunt has these pathes hardcoded

Comment: So far the best I've come up with is writing my Gruntfile in literate coffeescript, using coffee -c Gruntfile.litcoffee to compile it to js, and then running grunt. Pretty annoying... Hoping someone had a better solution.

Comment: well, if the compiling isn't too long, you probably can write a little cli module to do that, but I think that's overkill.

Comment: Sadly, I abandoned this experiment the day after I asked the question, and am no longer able to choose a valid answer because I have nothing set up to test the suggested solutions. I hope to return to it someday. If that day ever comes, I will come back and choose an answer... Thanks for the suggestions though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this your Gruntfile.coffee. You could just as easily do it as a js file of course, as long as node knows what litcoffee is supposed to parse like (that's why you require `coffee-script`)

```
coffee = require 'coffee-script'
module.exports = require './Gruntfile.litcoffee'
```

This is under the assumption that the litcoffee file's export is the `(grunt) -> function`

Answer (score 1):

You could have a Gruntfile.coffee act as a bootstrapper for the Gruntfile.litcoffee file, something like this pseudo code...

```
coffee = require "coffee-script"

module.exports = eval coffee.compile "Gruntfile.litcoffee"
```